# jQuery fadeIn works but disappears right away

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery and fadeIn to fade in pieces of content on a page.  It fades in properly, but the problem is that it fades out right after the fadeIn automatically in Android.  :-\

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // Fancy intro animation
    $(".scroll-button").fadeIn(1000);

    // Smooth the scrolling
    $(".scroll-button").click(function(event){
            var bodyElement;

            event.preventDefault();

            if($.browser.safari) {
                bodyElement = $("body")
            } else {
                bodyElement = $("html,body")
            }

            bodyElement.animate({
                scrollTop: $('#headerimage').position().top
            }, 500);

            $('.bottom-image').hide();
            $(this.hash).fadeIn(1500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found out that Android 2.3 doesn't handle click events and there are issues with it.  Even attaching jQuery mobile (earlier versions) didn't work.

Eventually adding a div around the image and calling the div instead, worked.  Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

`hash` only belongs to the `location` object. You're trying to fade in an element that doesn't exist (I suspect the jQuery constructor is actually the equivalent of $(undefined)).

Using the code that you've posted, `$(this.hash).fadeIn(1500)` is looking for the `hash` property of the `.scroll-button` element. Try changing that line to something like:

```
$(window.location.hash).fadeIn(1500);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that causes it not to load at all in Android.  Everything is fine in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, iOS...  just Android for some reason.